# How does a minute repeater work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I was wondering how a minute repeater works - it is a complication in a watch that chimes the hours, quarter hours, and minutes.

For instance, if you engaged the repeater, and the time was 2:47, the watch would chime

```
dong, dong, ding-dong, ding-dong, ding-dong, ding, ding
```

What are the mechanisms needed in order to make this happen? There are probably many ways to build one. How would one describe the workings of the simplest minute repeater possible?

Comment: There are many possible ways. You might be better off asking what specific field(s) of study within mechanical engineering could be used to design such mechanisms, or ask for specific examples of mechanisms could be used. IMO, besides the obvious gears, a system of cams and nothing more would be needed

Comment: Google  "Fizzbuzz"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that's not really pertinent to my question or helpful in any way.

Comment: Actually, it's completely relevant. Just because your watch uses a mechanical calculator to determine the output (aka the chime tones) doesn't mean the fundamental algorithm is any different.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it would be relevant if I had posted the question in a different community.  The question asks about the mechanisms, not the algorithm, even if the algorithm is implemented through the mechanism.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Said another way - you can tell me everything about the algorithm governing a minute repeater and I will have learned nothing about its implementation.